# How to improve the Python SQLAlchemy performance with AWS Lightsail?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-lightsail

I'm really surprised with the slow insertion of rows using SQLAlchemy with AWS Lightsail to the point that I believe I must be doing something wrong.

I can execute SQL commands through MySQL Workbench and they process in fractions of a second and I can use a local sqlite db and again super quick.  The same insertion using Lighsail takes > 14 seconds and 1500 rows doesn't feel like it's excessive.. I appreciate someone wouldn't have 1500 emails, it was just a quick example.

Am I doing this all wrong and there is a more efficient way of adding/committing/using Lightsail or is the performance actually bad?

```
# sqlite example
# Adding:  0:00:00.254232

# aws (Lightsail Database) 
# Adding:  0:00:14.022152
```

My code is just basic using the simple example in a tutorial:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker

import datetime

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    addresses = relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(50))
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('person.id'))

address_list = []
for email in range(1,1500):
    a = Address(email=str(email)+"@hotmail.com")
    address_list.append(a)

p = Person(name='foo', addresses=address_list)
# engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://username:password@lrds.amazonaws.com/awstest")
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///testing.sqlite")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
session = Session()
session.add(p)
session.commit()
time_end = datetime.datetime.now()
time_difference = time_end - time_start
print("Adding: ", time_difference)
print(p.addresses.count())

# sqlite example
# Adding:  0:00:00.254232

# aws (Lightsail Database) 
# Adding:  0:00:14.022152
```

Comment: do you know which segments are taking the most time? you're comparing full versions, but I'm curious if the connection is taking the time or the data movement.

Comment: it's the commit which is taking the time.  If I split out everything else, it's all the same within milliseconds.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: This is AWS Lightsail managed database. https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-databases it’s 1gb 1 Core 40gb SSD I have no hardware control and no ssh.

Comment: This URL will describe your ability to view/change database parameters - https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-updating-database-parameters    Can you login to your database and run SELECT NOW(); to get the system date and time?   If you can, you can do B) C) and D) from above.  If you have support, you can open a ticket asking for the OS information requested through your support team.

Comment: Isn’t the whole purpose of Lightsail that it’s managed? My question is just whether there is something wrong with my code approach and whether 14 seconds sounds reasonable.

Comment: Managed does not mean lightsail will provide tuning services.  The same as they will not add indexes to tables for you or remove redundant indexes.  Managed covers a lot of details and is great for most people.  View my profile, Network profile for free Utility Script download to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: This has not answered the question that I asked.  Am I doing this all wrong and there is a more efficient way of adding/committing/using Lightsail or is the performance actually bad? This is nothing to with redundant indexes or adding any additional indexes.  This is literally a brand new Lightsail and the code you see above. Even a Lightsail LAMP setup has better performance...

Comment: And a Lightsail LAMP is $3.50